# Auxílio com SQL

Tags: sql

Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema... tenho uma tabela XXX que tem os seguintes campos: **k803, codrer, periodo, meta,  desafio**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na tabela mostra mostra a meta e o desafio de cada representante da loja 802 no período de janeiro de 2018.

Precisei fazer a media dessa loja nesse período ficando assim: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A questão é a seguinte,  preciso fazer isso para todos os meses e colocar todas informações em uma consulta só,  por exemplo "Media da meta e desafio de janeiro" , "media da meta e e desafio de fevereiro "  ... e assim por diante.

*Query* da média:

```
SELECT  AVG(XXX.META)       AS META
    ,   AVG(XXX.DESAFIO)    AS DESAFIO 
FROM    XXX 
WHERE   XXX.K803    = '802' 
    AND XXX.periodo = '032018'
```

Alguém tem ideia se isso é possível ser feito ?

Comment: Coloque pf a _query_ SQL que utilizou para chegar à média que indicou na sua questão. Evite também colocar imagens da consulta ou resultados, coloque em texto formatado que é de mais fácil leitura (e facilita o _copy/paste_!).

Comment: Perfeito ..valeu pelas dicas. Segue a Query da média. 

SELECT AVG(XXX.META) AS META,AVG(XXX.DESAFIO) AS DESAFIO FROM XXX WHERE XXX.K803 = '802' AND XXX.periodo = '012018'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que algo assim resolve o seu problema:

```
SELECT      X.K803
        ,   X.CODREPR
        ,   X.PERIODO
        ,   X2.META
        ,   X2.DESAFIO
FROM        XXX X   
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      K803
                        ,   PERIODO
                        ,   AVG(META)       AS META
                        ,   AVG(DESAFIO)    AS DESAFIO
                FROM        XXX
                GROUP BY    K803
                        ,   PERIODO
            )   X2  ON  X2.K803     = X.K803
                    AND X2.PERIODO  = X.PERIODO
```

Depois pode sempre aplicar os filtros que entender.

---

Se não necessitar da coluna `CODREPR` então pode fazer de uma vez só!

```
SELECT      K803
        ,   PERIODO
        ,   AVG(META)       AS META
        ,   AVG(DESAFIO)    AS DESAFIO
FROM        XXX
GROUP BY    K803
        ,   PERIODO
WHERE       K803 = '802'
```

A cláusula `WHERE` é opcional. Se a incluir, apenas irá devolver os resultados para a loja '802', se remover irá devolver para todas as lojas.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, fazer testes e aviso depois aqui,  em um primeiro momento não deu resultado dessa forma. Mas vou ver o que pode ser,

Comment: Na verdade nao vou precisar do codrepr, só uma pergunta, coloco o GROUP BY ali logo após o FROM e abaixo disso eu mantenho o INNER JOIN até o final,  correto ?

Comment: Se não precisa da coluna `CODREPR` não precisa manter o `INNER JOIN`. Fica exatamente como está na minha 2ª consulta.

Comment: Perfeito, e caso eu queira pegar somente os dados da k803 = '802' tem como ? Colocar um WHERE no final é possivel  ?

Comment: Sim, claro :). Resposta editada para incluir filtros.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda,  tudo funcionando conforme o esperado. Obrigado

Comment: Feliz por ajudar! Se a resposta lhe foi útil então marque-a como aceite e dê um UP!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87835/discussion-between-joao-martins-and-alexandre-prezzi).